# What does never do in Array<string>[never]?

Tags: typescript

For example,

```
type A = Array<string>[never]; // A is string
```

How to understand `never` here? For example, can we use `any` here? and what is the difference if any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally `T[K]` is a [indexed type access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html). Where `K` needs to be a possible key of `T`. So `Array<string>[never]` is an indexed type access where `T` is `Array<string>` and `K` is `never`.

To understand why `Array<string>[never]` works, let's first see what you could and couldn't index `Array<string>` with:

1. You can't index with `string` ( [`Array<string>[string]`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8sBOSCGIA8BnYSCWAdgOYB8A2jvsQLoDcQA) is an error) This is because `Array` does not have a index signature, so indexing with a random string is not allowed.
2. You could index with a specific `string` literal type representing a member of `Array` (ex [`Array<string>['map']`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=10&pln=1&pc=30#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8sBOSCGIA8BnYSCWAdgOYB8A2gOQC2qYFAugNxA) works)
3. You can index with `number`, as `Array` has an index signature with for `number` (ex: [`Array<string>[number]`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=31&pln=1&pc=10#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8sBOSCGIA8BnYSCWAdgOYB8A2gQK4C2ARhEgLoDcQA) is `string`)
4. You can index with a subtype of number. For example you can index with the number literal type `0`. Here TS will look for an index signature that can be matched to the number literal type and it will find the number index signature.  It will match this index signature because `0` is assignable to `number`. So [`Array<string>[0]`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=10&pln=1&pc=26#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8sBOSCGIA8BnYSCWAdgOYB8A2gAwC6A3EA) will be `string`

So why can we index with `never`? Well `never` is by [definition](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8652) the subtype of any other type (ie, it is assignable to any other type). This means `never` is also a subtype of, and assignable to `number` ([ex](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAdgbgTgLmiGI4QLzQK7GAQgG4AoUSKRHAWwCM1Np5Cg)). Since `never` is a subtype of `number`, the number signature can be used to index with `never`, just as it can be used for `0`. This is why [`Array<string>[never]`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8sBOSCGIA8BnYSCWAdgOYB8A2gRAG4RIC6QA) resolves to `string`

Comment: I have accepted your answer, but still confused - since `never` is subtype of any other type, `Array<string>['never']` can also be inferred from `Array<string>['map']`, but `map` can return any type. So how does TS compiler choose the correct version?

Comment: @ABOS It will only look for indexes, with priority being given to `number` indexes. This is probably a design decision, You can make the argument that `Array<string>[never]` should also give you the type of `map` as well.